# How to connect to work VPN when also have personal VPN?

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I work from home and need to connect to work's VPN. I also have a Surfshark as a personal VPN with OpenVPN protocol. Only one works at a time.

My router is an RT-AC86U.

See image. Solid lines are functional, while broken lines are not.

My network:

[image: my network]

I tried port forwarding, enabled DMZ, NAT passthrough:

[image: tried]

Comment: When you mention Surfshark as a personal VPN, does it come with a client that you would install on your desktop? If so, the surfshark personal VPN would come on the desktop side (before the router). That way, you are choosing which VPN client to use to negotiate with the corresponding VPN Server to encrypt the connection.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is quite a pain and has nothing to do with my router settings. I needed to get a VPN service that has Port Forwarding.

I settled with PureVPN and not only did I have to pay extra for the port forwarding feature, it is set on the vendor site itself not in my router